# Ruby: Array contained in Array, any order

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, subset

Suppose I have the following Ruby code:

```
array_1 = ['a', 'b']
array_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

some_function(array_1, array_2) # => True
some_function(array_2, array_1) # => False
some_function(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'd']) # => False
some_function(['x', 'y'], array_2) # => False
```

I am pretty much looking for `some_function` to return True when Parameter 2 contains *all* of the elements in Parameter 1.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
def f a,b
    (a-b).empty?
end
```

Comment: This is what I like about Ruby - so concise, sensible and readable.

Answer (score 1):

From a previous post,

```
def f a,b
    (a-b).empty?
end
```

will not work the way you expect, for example:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a2 = [2, 3, 5, 9]

(a1-a2).empty? # returns true
```

however,

```
a1-a2 # returns [1, 4, 6, 7, 8], not empty
```

thus `f` returns false.

A more accurate solution, if you want a one-liner would be:

```
def f a,b
    a&b == b
end
```

`a&b` will return all elements that are in both `a` and `b` then we check to see if that is equal to `b`

For ambiguity sake:

```
def f a,b
    (a&b == a) || (a&b == b)
end
```

Comment: This is because you should put bigger array in the first place. Author actually asks whether array `a` is a subset of `b`. Obviously, in your example `a1` is not a subset of `a2`

Comment: `a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` ; 
`a2 = [2, 3, 5, 9]` ;
`(a1-a2).empty?` # => returns `false` !! ;
Did I do something wrong or did you??

Answer (score -2):

```
def f a,b
    tmp  = a.map(|i| b.include?(i))
    tmp.include?(false)
end
```