# Check if each element of an array is included in a set of values of another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to check if each element of an array is included in a set of values present in another array.

That is, I have these arrays:

```
array1 = [1,3]
array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I would check if values in `array1` are all present in the `array2`. *I should return `true` if at least one of `array1` is different from values in `array2`*

How can I code that in a Ruby "good" way?

P.S.: I read this solution, but it is for Java's arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Array contained in Array, any order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897525/ruby-array-contained-in-array-any-order)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to do a [set intersection](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000274) and see what you get from that:

```
intersection = array1 & array2
if intersection.length == array1.length
    # Everything in array1 is in array2
end
```

That would, of course, fail if `array1` had duplicates as the intersection will automatically compress those. But we have [`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000276) to take care of that:

```
intersection = array1 & array2
if intersection.length == array1.uniq.length
    # Everything in array1 is in array2
end
```

If you're expecting duplicates in your arrays then you'd be better off working with instances of [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html) rather than arrays:

```
require 'set'
s1 = Set.new(array1)
s2 = Set.new(array2)

if((s1 & s2) == s1)
    # Everything in array1 is in array2
end
```

Or use [`subset?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html#M003473) to better match your intentions:

```
if(s1.subset?(s2))
    # Everything in array1 is in array2
end
```

Using sets will take care of your duplicate issues with less noise than having to use `uniq` all the time. There would, of course, be a bit of extra overhead but you should optimize for clarity before performance (make it work then make it fast only if it is too slow).

Answer (score 0):

```
includes = true

array1.each do |elem|
  if !array2.include?(elem)
    includes = false
  end
end
```

And you'll have in  `includes` variable what you need

Comment: there's a functional abstraction for that: Enumerable#all?

Comment: Why keep looking once you've found an element missing?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game.. but

```
(array2 & array1) === array1
```

That seems to work..

```
array1.present? && (array2 & array1) === array1
```

if you want to return true if the array has data.

I took a stab at the === operator, as it works in rspec.

Answer (score -1):

This can work

```
newarray = array1 & array2
```